# What the view controller structure/hierarchy of the iPhone photos app?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on an app that requires a pushing a view that is full screen and shows/hides status, navigation and bottom toolbars on tapping of the central image. The app currently has a UITabBarController that has a UINavigationController for each tab. Basically when the full screen view is displayed I want it to to work like the photos app and animate off the tab bar to show my full screen view.

I'm having trouble making the view take up the full screen if I manually animate out (down) or hide the tabbar.

So, in a nutshell, my question is - what is the view hierarchy of the photos app?

It must have a base navigation controller, that contains a tab bar controller. But does each tab contain another navigation controller? But if so, how to they seem to share the navigation bar with the root navigation controller (look at how the back buttons etc are animated in)?

Is there something really obvious I'm missing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `UIViewController`'s `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property?

Comment: Awesome, never seen that before, thanks! Will accept this as I guess this helps me understand the structure, and also helps me with my app.